# Book Content Classification With Artificial Intelligence

Tags: c#, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, ml.net

I have a lot of e-books and i want to develop a search engine which gets input search from people and finds related part in books with given search text.

I think about using Microsoft ML.NET to do it. This article shows how to categorize text content:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/github-issue-classification

But I need that ai algorithm have to separate book's content to topics. How can i do that?

Comment: Interesting idea. However, you will likely need to build and train custom models to do this for you, which will inevitably take you down the proverbial rabbit-hole of ML data sciences.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the answer. Do you know any article or content which helps me to separate book's content meaningful topics?